# Convert html file with images in base64 format to doc

Tags: java, file, base64

I am trying to read the file in using buffered reader.

```
String totalStr = "";
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    totalStr += s + "\n";
}
```

When `s` consist of base64 image, the string is half cut in between also i'm not able to append rest of the contents of the files to totalstr.

How can i handle base64 image string as it consists of special characters?

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest do not use readLine() method, since this method may read more black characters or extra encodings.

If you only want to convert a image with base64 to String:

The following class includes two methods:
Converts a image to Base64 String and Decode it

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class ImageToBase64 {

    public static String GetImageStr(String imgFile) {
        // Convert the image file to byte array, and do Base64 encoding
        InputStream in = null;
        byte[] data = null;
        // Read Image Data Array
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(imgFile);
            data = new byte[in.available()];
            in.read(data);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Base64 Encoding
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        return encoder.encode(data);// Return the string encoded by Base64
    }

    public static boolean GenerateImage(String base64str, String savepath) { 
        // Decoding the string and generate the image
        if (base64str == null) 
            return false;
        System.out.println("Decoding Start...");
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        try {
            // Base64 Decoding
            byte[] b = decoder.decodeBuffer(base64str);
            System.out.println("Decoding End...");
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
                if (b[i] < 0) {
                    b[i] += 256;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Start Generating Image");
            // Gen the jpeg image
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(savepath);
            out.write(b);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String image  = GetImageStr("C:/Users/Perspectivar/Downloads/001.jpg");

        System.out.println(image);
        GenerateImage(image,"C:/Users/Perspectivar/Desktop/SYZ01.jpg");
    }

}
```